# How to use Python iterators elegantly

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I am trying to use iterators more for looping since I heard it is faster than index looping. One thing I am not sure is about how to treat the end of the sequence nicely. The way I can think of is to use `try` and `except StopIteration`, which looks ugly to me.

To be more concrete, suppose we are asked to print the merged sorted list of two sorted lists `a` and `b`. I would write the following

```
aNull = False
I = iter(a)
try:
    tmp = I.next()
except StopIteration:
    aNull = True

for x in b:
    if aNull:
        print x
    else:
        if x < tmp:
            print x
        else:
            print tmp,x
            try:
                tmp = I.next()
            except StopIteration:
                aNull = True

while not aNull:
    print tmp
    try:
        tmp = I.next()
    except StopIteration:
        aNull = True
```

How would you code it to make it neater?

Comment: That code is almost illegible. Describe what it's supposed to do.

Comment: a and b are two sorted lists. the task is to print the elements of these two lists in nondecreasing order

Comment: So you need to merge two sorted lists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think handling `a` and `b` more symmetrically would make it easier to read.  Also, using the built-in `next` function in Python 2.6 with a default value avoids the need to handle `StopIteration`:

```
def merge(a, b):
    """Merges two iterators a and b, returning a single iterator that yields
    the elements of a and b in non-decreasing order.  a and b are assumed to each
    yield their elements in non-decreasing order."""

    done = object()
    aNext = next(a, done)
    bNext = next(b, done)

    while (aNext is not done) or (bNext is not done):
        if (bNext is done) or ((aNext is not done) and (aNext < bNext)):
            yield aNext
            aNext = next(a, done)
        else:
            yield bNext
            bNext = next(b, done)

for i in merge(iter(a), iter(b)):
    print i
```

The following function generalizes the approach to work for arbitrarily many iterators.

```
def merge(*iterators):
    """Merges a collection of iterators, returning a single iterator that yields
    the elements of the original iterators in non-decreasing order.  Each of
    the original iterators is assumed to yield its elements in non-decreasing
    order."""

    done = object()
    n = [next(it, done) for it in iterators]

    while any(v is not done for v in n):
        v, i = min((v, i) for (i, v) in enumerate(n) if v is not done)
        yield v
        n[i] = next(iterators[i], done)
```

Comment: Of course, if you actually want to merge two lists you should use the standard library function `heapq.merge`.

Comment: This would be even better if done as a generator - pass a and b into it and replace the `print` statements with `yield`.  Then you could do whatever you want with the result and it wouldstill be an iterator.

Comment: @neil Agreed.  I thought of that but didn't think it was worth the extra complexity for this example.  But since you've mentioned it too, I think I'll rewrite it as you suggest.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing the whole point of iterators. You don't manually call `I.next()`, you just iterate through `I`.

```
for tmp in I:
    print tmp
```

**Edited**

To merge two iterators, use the very handy functions in the `itertools` module. The one you want is probably [`izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

```
merged = []
for x, y in itertools.izip(a, b):
    if x < y:
        merged.append(x)
        merged.append(y)
    else:
        merged.append(y)
        merged.append(x)
```

**Edit again**

As pointed out in the comments, this won't actually work, because there could be multiple items from list a smaller than the next item in list b. However, I realised that there is another built-in funciton that deals with this: [`heapq.merge`](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge).

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to merge two iterators using `for`.

Comment: That won't work - there might be multiple items from one iterator between two from the other.

Comment: @neil yes, I just realised that. Will have to think some more.

Answer (score 0):

The function  `sorted`  works with lists and iterators. Maybe it is not what you desire, but the following code works.

```
a.expand(b)
print sorted(iter(a))
```

Comment: sorted transform iter(a) into a list and then sorts it, so you're not using generators...